# Why collection length is 0 but fetch succeeded?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My todos.js:

```
var app = app || {};

(function () {
    'use strict';
    var Todos = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: app.Todo,
        url: '/api/todos'
    });
    app.todos = new Todos();
})();
```

app-view.js

```
var app = app || {};
(function($){
    'use strict';
    app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.todoapp',
        events : {
            'keypress .new-todo': 'createOnEnter'

        },

        initialize: function() {
            this.$input = this.$('.new-todo');
            this.$list = $('.todo-list');
            app.todos.fetch( {
                reset : true
            } );
            this.render();
        },


        render: function(){
            console.log( ' len = ' +  app.todos.length );
            app.todos.each( function(todo){
                this.renderTodo( todo );
            }, this );
        },
...
```

**Fetched data**

```
[{
    "_id": "5801",
    "title": "testtitle123",
    "completed": false,
    "__v": 0
}, {
    "_id": "58182",
    "title": "testtitle126",
    "completed": false,
    "__v": 0
}, {
    "_id": "5813",
    "title": "testtitle127",
    "completed": false,
    "__v": 0
}]
```

It succeeded to fetch data (from http://myip:8000/api/todos). But from the console, the length is always 0.

**UPDATE**

I tried the following codes. but no 'OK' or 'error' logged in console.

```
    var app = app || {};
    (function($){
        'use strict';
        app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: '.todoapp',
            events : {
                'keypress .new-todo': 'createOnEnter'

            },

            initialize: function() {
                this.$input = this.$('.new-todo');
                this.$list = $('.todo-list');
                this.listenTo(app.todos, 'sync', this.render);
                app.todos.fetch( {
                    reset : true,
                    context: this,
                    success: function(col, res, op) {
                        console.log( 'OK' );
                    },
                    error: function(col, res, op){
                        console.log( 'error' );
                    }
                } );
            },

            render: function(){
                console.log( ' len = ' +  app.todos.length );
                app.todos.each( function(todo){
                    this.renderTodo( todo );
                }, this );
            },

            renderTodo: function( todo ) {
                console.log( 'render :' + todo.title );
                var todoView = new app.TodoView( { model : todo } );
                this.$list.append( todoView.render().el );
            },
        });

    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: What's the received data?

Comment: Please, do not edit in the code from answer into your question as it makes the answers irrelevant and prone to confusion.

Comment: At that point, the other code should work, so you'll need to investigate. Is it because the `render` is called from somewhere else?

Comment: @EmileBergeron Thanks, I donot think so.

Comment: Is the `initialize` even called?

Comment: @EmileBergeron called.

Comment: @EmileBergeron fixed the error now, it is because the order of importing js files was wrong. Sorry for the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) is asynchronous, so when you render immediately after, the collection is still empty.

Any function that needs to call the server is asynchronous by definition. They can't be synchronous without locking the browser.

Use the callbacks offered by Backbone to easily solve this:

```
initialize: function() {
    /** ...snip... */
    app.todos.fetch({ 
        reset: true,
        context: this,
        success: this.render
    });
},
```

Also, if the data received from the API is in the format:

```
{
    data: [
        {...},
        {...}
    ]
}
```

You need to provide a `parse` function in your collection:

```
var Todos = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Todo,
    url: '/api/todos',
    parse: function(response) {
        return response.data;
    }
});
```

```js
var PostCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
});


var collection = new PostCollection();
collection.fetch({
  reset: true,
  context: this,
  success: function() {
    console.log("Success:", collection.length);
  }
});

Simplest demo of fetching and checking the `length`.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because all fetches are async. So your render is running before it fetches your todos.

You could rerender once the fetch is done:

```
app.todos.fetch().done(function(){
   self.render();
});
```

You could also listen to the sync event of your model:

```
this.listenTo(app.todos, 'sync', this.render);
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Sync

Comment: Using the jQuery promise API here isn't necessary.

Comment: @n00btron fixed the error now, it is because the order of importing js files was wrong. Sorry for the time.